# spring auth - move from xml to java config

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-java-config

after moving to java config based auth can not pass auth step
could somebody explain, how to implement authenticationManager?

now i am getting

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

when i trying get token through http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user@awesome.com&password=cant_hack_this&client_id=sso-auth-client&client_secret=mySecret

here is repo https://github.com/mikesockor/SOFqstn

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
//@ImportResource({"classpath*:spring-security-oauth2.xml"})
```

how to implement this?

```
<sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"  authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" >
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token"  />
    <sec:anonymous enabled="true" />
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />  
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<sec:http auto-config="true"  pattern="/oauth/check_token"  create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/check_token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
</sec:http>

<sec:http pattern="/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" >
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>
```

also if i will try to

```
#security.basic.enabled=false
security.ignored=/**
```

getting

```
{
    "timestamp": 1491919124442,
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/oauth/token"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a full configuration of Spring Auth with Boot you will need the following

First, you have to implement the basic class for Configure the Spring Auth

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AccountAuthenticatoinProvider accountAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(accountAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Next you will need the ResourceServerConfiguration and AuthorizationServerConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        .....
        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources
                    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).tokenStore(new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter));
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();



            // @formatter:on
        }

....

    }



    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

      .....
        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                    .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("123456");
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }
.....

}
```

Please view the following git repo https://github.com/cpapidas/Spring-Boot-OAuth2-JWT-MySQL